# Reactjs - server/client checksum mismatch error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have React render a component on the server first, then change the state on the client side with a button. I have followed several tutorials which state to put the component in the same node on the server and client with the same props to do something like this. However, I'm still getting an invalid checksum error message, and attempting to click the button causes the browser to crash. Any ideas where I went wrong?

The component:

```
var React = require('react')

module.exports = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return { from: this.props.from }
},
handleClick: function(){
    this.setState({
        from: !this.state.clicked ? 'client!' : 'server!',
        clicked: !this.state.clicked
    });
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                This is from the HelloWorld.jsx component's render function.
            </div>
            <div>
                Rendered from: {this.state.from}
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick={this.handleClick} />
        </div>
    )
}})
```

The browser:

```
var React = require('react')
var HelloWorld = require('../Components/HelloWorld')

var helloElement = React.render(
    <HelloWorld from = "server!" />,
    document.getElementById("reactHelloContainer"))
```

The server:

```
var React = require('react')
  , express = require('express')
  , HelloWorld = require('./Components/HelloWorld')
  , path = require('path')

var app = express()
app.use('/pages', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Pages')))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    var html = React.renderToString(
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Hello World</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="reactHelloContainer">
                            <HelloWorld from="server!" />
                    </div>
                </body>
                <script src="/pages/index.js"></script>
            </html>)
    res.end(html)
})
```

I have tried loading the page without Javascript and the server/client versions seem to be identical, but this is the message:

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
>
> (client) eactid=".1566xf5m134">
>
> (server) eactid=".1566xf5m134.1.1.0">

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The initial state set in `getInitialState` from the server needs to match the initial state in the browser.  One way to accomplish this is passing the initial props to the browser in a script tag, and then getting the props from the contents of the script.  You can pass the props in using templating.

Browser HTML:

```
<div id='reactHelloContainer'></div>
<script id='hello-props'> {Your props in JSON here}   </script>
```

Browser js:

```
var React = require('react');
var HelloWorld = require('../Components/HelloWorld');

component = React.createFactory(HelloWorld);
var props = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("hello-props").innerHTML);
React.render(component(props), document.getElementById('reactHelloContainer'));
```

Comment: Please don't do this

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola it would be helpful if you could expand on why this is a bad idea.  I am also curious if you have alternatives for setting the initial state.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the norm, actually.. This starter is doing something similar: https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example. Notice how hes not inlining the props directly and fetching them with a json parse... This seems contrarian to React or Javascriptisms. You would be better off putting them in window.__PREFETCHED_DATA__ or something like that.

Comment: Then again the server side rendering I have done and played with does not look like either of your examples, so I might be doing something different. I have not tried such things from scratch though, so it might be that the details are just abstracted from my perspective.

Comment: The example you linked to does something similar; they inject JavaScript into the markup to set a variable containing the initial state. I don't see any inherent advantage to doing it that way.